# How do I display an Excel dropdown of values in the terminal shell?

Tags: python, excel

I currently have a script that has a user input values into an excel sheet via python and then makes a copy of that sheet into a new file. In the original excel sheet, there is one value I am trying to populate that consists of an Excel dropdown of values. I want to display this dropdown of values to the user inside the terminal shell and then have the user select one.

---

Current Code:

```
policy_master = raw_input('Which master does this Standard reference? (Please '
                          'choose from one of the following below:')

print "Script now starting"

new_file = standard_name + ".xlsx"

data_input = (("Planning", "phase"), (standard_name,"Version_Name"),
              (version,"Version"), (policy_owner, "Policy_Document Owner"),
              ("IT Risk Leaders", "Approval_Body"),
              (project_manager, "Project_Manager"), ("001", "Version_History"),
              ("Standard", "Document_Type"), ("IT_Governance", "Trigger"),
              (policy_master, "Policy_Document_Master_Reference"))

filename = "PLD_Master_Template"
sheet_name= "Policy Document Version"
```

---

List of dropdown values:

[image: List of dropdown values]

Comment: The terminal shell isn't a GUI, so I doubt you can display a dropdown of values.